# Windows10クライアントからWindowsServer2012R2 のファイルサーバにアクセスしようと「ネットワーク エラー」と表示される。

Tags: windows, windows-10

#### 現状の問題点

Windows10クライアントからWindowsServer2012R2 のファイルサーバにアクセスしようとした際、いくつかの問題が起きています。

1. エクスプローラのアドレスバーに `\\\サーバのIPアドレス` と入力すると、以下のメッセージが表示され、サーバの共有フォルダの一覧が表示できません。

   **エラーメッセージ**

   ```
   「ネットワーク エラー」
   \\\サーバのIPアドレス にアクセスできません
   \\\サーバのIPアドレス に対するアクセス許可がありません。ネットワーク管理者にアクセス許可を要求してください。
   ```
2. `\\\サーバのIPアドレス\共有名` と入力すると、10秒以上かかって、共有フォルダを開くことができます。(実用には耐えませんが)

#### 解決したいこと

1. `\\\サーバのIPアドレス` で、サーバの共有フォルダの一覧を表示できるようにしたい。
2. `\\\サーバのIPアドレス\共有名` で共有フォルダの内容が表示できるようにしたい。(一応できますが10秒以上かかるので)
3. クライアントPC上のアプリケーション(PowerBI等)から共有フォルダ内のデータファイルを開きたい。

原因と解決方法を教えてください。

---

#### クライアント環境

Windows10Pro x64 1903
ドメインメンバー
IPはDHCP
WindowsDefenderファイアウォール:無効

#### サーバ環境

Windows Server 2012R2
ワークグループ
IPはスタティック
ネットワークプロファイル:プライベート
ネットワーク探索を無効にする
ファイルとプリンタの共有を有効にする
すべてのネットワークプロファイルで
パブリックフォルダの共有:共有を有効にしてネットワークアクセスがある場合はパブリックフォルダー内のファイルを読み書きできるようにする
パスワード保護:パスワード保護共有を無効にする

ネットワーク設定
固定IPアドレス
NetBIOS設定:規定値(NetBIOS over TCP/IP 有効)
Windows ファイアウォール:すべてのプロファイルで無効
役割と機能:SMB 1.0/CIFS ファイル共有のサポート インストール済み
レジストリで HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentContoroleSet\Services\LanmanServer\ParametersでSMB1を0 に設定
共有フォルダは、C:\Usrs\ユーザ名\Documents\共有名 で、Everyone に読み取りを許可しています。

#### ネットワーク環境

- クライアントが居るセグメントとサーバのセグメント間にF/Wあり。
- クライアントセグメント → サーバのIPで445/TCPとICMPを許可。
- サーバはDNSで引けるFQDNを持ってますが、ここではIPアドレスで指定。
- クライアント → サーバ間のエラー発生時のパケットはキャプチャしています。

`xxx.xxx.22.192` がクライアント、`xxxx.xxxx.121.27` がファイルサーバです。

[image: パケットキャプチャした画像]

Comment: 「クライアントが居るセグメントとサーバのセグメント間にF/Wあり」と書かれていますが、そもそも異なるネットワークセグメント間で通信するためには、２つのセグメントをつなぐルータがないとダメです。ネットワーク、ルータなどのネットワーク機器を含んだネットワーク構成を示してください。

Comment: クライアントのセグメント - L3 - コアスイッチ+F/W - L3 - サーバセグメントというネットワーク構成です。